Transform nested, unequal and multi-layered JSON column present in a dataframe into new columns and rows inside the same dataframe in R
I need to deal with this dataframe that contains two columns of nested and unequally rowed layers inside a dataframe, I need to expand widely what is possible in  these columns.
 jsonblob1 = c("{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}","{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}")
 jsonblob2 = c("{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}","{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"]}")
 otherc1 = c(1,2)
 otherc2 = c(2,5)

 df = data.frame(jsonblob1,jsonblob2,otherc1,otherc2)

I have tried so far with this piece of code that I have previously used to expand other multilayered JSONs
 df |> 
   mutate(
     jsonblob1 = map(jsonblob1, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x) |> 
                       unnest_wider(everything()) |> 
                       unnest_wider(everything(), names_sep = "_") |> 
                       mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))) |>
   mutate(
     jsonblob2 = map(jsonblob2, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x) |> 
                       unnest_wider(everything()) |> 
                       unnest_wider(everything(), names_sep = "_") |> 
                       mutate(across(everything(), as.character))))
       unnest(jsonblob1,jsonblob2) |>  
       type_convert() 

But it returns this error and I have not been able to fix it.
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `jsonblob1 = map(...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `unnest_wider()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, not a list.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Just to make sure the objective is clear, I want to expand all the layers which contain a single row into the same row when possible and those elements with multiple rows (such as crits in the example) I want to know how to expand them wider or longer (repeating single observations to match the number of rows in the unequeal element).
Also, the jsonblob intentionally contains an element that has length(0), but sometimes it also has information on it as in second row in jsonblob2, so the solution should be flexible.
I appreciate the help.
[UPDATE] Sorry if I was not clear enough. I am expecting to get the two different jsons (jsonblob1 and jsonblob2) to be spread wider in new columns. When I said that should be flexible, I also meant that it should consider the case also that jsonblobs are not exactly equal so it would not fit under the same column scheme as @margusl response suggests. Ideally, I want every layer inside the json spread wider producing new columns, and every row in each of these layers (if there are more than one, like in the case of crits) in new rows (spreading longer which would aslo affect to the repetition of every other observation in every other column in the dataframe as a consequence of producing those additional rows).

Not to sure about the expected output. Does lapply(df[grep("jsonblob", colnames(df))], \(i) lapply(i, jsonlite::fromJSON)         |> Reduce(f = rbind)) |> Reduce(f = rbind) |> as.data.frame() get you started? Do you want crits and tasksto be seperated in additional columns?

Hi, sorry I was not clear enough, I've updated my post with more details.

Does this give you what you'd like to achieve?
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

jsonblob1 = c("{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}","{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}")
jsonblob2 = c("{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[]}","{\"basestep_id\":\"BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderflht3o\",\"step_act\":\"SET_NEW\",\"step_count\":0,\"custm\":false,\"edited\":false,\"name\":null,\"text\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"crits\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"],\"tasks\":[\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\\u2019 Lorem ipsum dolor sit. \\u2018Lorem ipsum dolor sit..\\u2019\",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.\"]}")
otherc1 = c(1,2)
otherc2 = c(2,5)

df = data.frame(jsonblob1,jsonblob2,otherc1,otherc2)

df |>
  mutate(across(contains("blob"), \(x) map(x, fromJSON) |>
    map(compact) |>
    map(as_tibble))) |> 
  unnest_longer(contains("blob")) |> 
  unnest(contains("blob"), names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 10 × 17
#>    jsonblob1_basestep_id jsonblob1_step_act jsonblob1_step_count jsonblob1_custm
#>    <chr>                 <chr>                             <int> <lgl>          
#>  1 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  2 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  3 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  4 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  5 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  6 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  7 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  8 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#>  9 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#> 10 BSa7pt5o7xx8dxaderfl… SET_NEW                               0 FALSE          
#> # ℹ 13 more variables: jsonblob1_edited <lgl>, jsonblob1_text <chr>,
#> #   jsonblob1_crits <chr>, jsonblob2_basestep_id <chr>,
#> #   jsonblob2_step_act <chr>, jsonblob2_step_count <int>,
#> #   jsonblob2_custm <lgl>, jsonblob2_edited <lgl>, jsonblob2_text <chr>,
#> #   jsonblob2_crits <chr>, jsonblob2_tasks <chr>, otherc1 <dbl>, otherc2 <dbl>

Created on 2024-05-04 with reprex v2.1.0

Yes, sorry for my delay in the response. Thanks very much!
